# How to customise font size of Table of Contents generated by package{tocloft} in LATEX

Tags: latex

I am using document class "report" and package {tocloft}. I am having a problem in changing font size of sections, chapters, subsections explicitly on Table of Contents generated by "\tableofcontents". It is actually taking the size of contents as they are present in  report but I want to alter the font size of table of contents page .

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{tocloft,lipsum,pgffor}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}% Include up to \subsubsection in ToC

\renewcommand{\cftpartfont}{\normalfont\sffamily\bfseries}% \part font in ToC
\renewcommand{\cftchapfont}{\normalfont\large\itshape}    % \chapter font in ToC
\renewcommand{\cftsecfont}{\normalfont\slshape}           % \section font in ToC
\renewcommand{\cftsubsecfont}{\normalfont\itshape}        % \subsection font in ToC
\renewcommand{\cftsubsubsecfont}{\normalfont\small}       % \subsubsection font in ToC

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents% ToC

% Create a dummy document with multiple (5) levels of sectional units
\foreach \curpart in {\Huge First, Second, Third, Last} {
  \part{\curpart{} part}
  \foreach \curchap in {\huge First, Second, Third, Last} {
    \chapter{\curchap{} chapter} \lipsum[1]
    \foreach \cursec in {\LARGE First, Second, Third, Last} {
      \section{\cursec{} section}\lipsum[2]
      \foreach \cursubsec in {First, Second, Third, Last} {
        \subsection{\cursubsec{} subsection}\lipsum[3]
        \foreach \cursubsubsec in {First, Second, Third, Last} {
          \subsubsection{\cursubsubsec{} subsubsection}\lipsum[4]
        }% \subsubsection
      }% \subsection
    }% \section
  }% \chapter
}% \part

\end{document}
```

I have added \huge and \LARGE in section headings in dummy document.

```
\foreach \curchap in {\huge First, Second, Third, Last} {
    \chapter{\curchap{} chapter} \lipsum[1]
    \foreach \cursec in {\LARGE First, Second, Third, Last} {
```

Doing this also reflects the change in size of that section heading in TOC page.
[Before adding \huge and \LARGE inside the section heading](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YH7ht.png)

[After](https://i.stack.imgur.com/10yvM.png)

I want to make font size of sections and chapter headings in TOC page to be independent of what happens to them inside the document.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should avoid using font changes within the sectional unit title, as these make their way into the ToC by default. For the odd change in font, I'd suggest using

```
\section[<ToC entry>]{<document entry>}
```

where you can specify whatever you want inside `<document entry>`, but leave `<ToC entry>` without any font changes. For a more global approach to setting fonts for sectional units, use a package that provides hooks to font settings for `<ToC entry>` and `<document entry>`, respectively.

`<document entry>` font changes is made easy using [`sectsty`](//ctan.org/pkg/sectsty) or [`titlesec`](//ctan.org/pkg/titlesec), while `<ToC entry>` changes is most typically made using [`tocloft`](//ctan.org/pkg/tocloft) or [`titletoc`](//ctan.org/pkg/titletoc). Specific to `sectsty`, redefine `\Xfont` for the sectional unit `X`. For example,

```
\renewcommand{\partfont}{\normalfont\Huge\bfseries}
```

will affect only the `<document content>` of `\part`, leaving the `<ToC entry>` untouched (and without font changes).

For each sectional unit `X` within the ToC, `tocloft` provides `\cftZfont` where `X` denotes (from the [`tocloft` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/tocloft/tocloft.pdf), section **2.3 Typesetting entries**):

- `part` for `\part` titles
- `chap` for `\chapter` titles
- `sec` for `\section` titles
- `subsec` for `\subsection` titles
- `subsubsec` for `\subsubsection` titles
- `para` for `\paragraph` titles
- `subpara` for `\subparagraph` titles
- `fig` for figure `\caption` titles
- `subfig` for subfigure `\caption` titles
- `tab` for table `\caption` titles
- `subtab` for subtable `\caption` titles

Here's an example of how to change the various components associated with different sectional units:

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{tocloft,lipsum,pgffor,sectsty}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}% Include up to \subsubsection in ToC

% Font changes to ToC content of sectional units
\renewcommand{\cftpartfont}{\normalfont\sffamily\bfseries}% \part font in ToC
\renewcommand{\cftchapfont}{\normalfont\large\itshape}    % \chapter font in ToC
\renewcommand{\cftsecfont}{\normalfont\slshape}           % \section font in ToC
\renewcommand{\cftsubsecfont}{\normalfont\itshape}        % \subsection font in ToC
\renewcommand{\cftsubsubsecfont}{\normalfont\small}       % \subsubsection font in ToC

% Font changes to document content of sectional units
\renewcommand{\partfont}{\normalfont\Huge\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\chapterfont}{\normalfont\huge\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\sectionfont}{\normalfont\LARGE\bfseries}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents% ToC

% Create a dummy document with multiple (5) levels of sectional units
\foreach \curpart in {First, Second, Third, Last} {
  \part{\curpart{} part}
  \foreach \curchap in {First, Second, Third, Last} {
    \chapter{\curchap{} chapter} \lipsum[1]
    \foreach \cursec in {First, Second, Third, Last} {
      \section{\cursec{} section}\lipsum[2]
      \foreach \cursubsec in {First, Second, Third, Last} {
        \subsection{\cursubsec{} subsection}\lipsum[3]
        \foreach \cursubsubsec in {First, Second, Third, Last} {
          \subsubsection{\cursubsubsec{} subsubsection}\lipsum[4]
        }% \subsubsection
      }% \subsection
    }% \section
  }% \chapter
}% \part

\end{document}
```

Comment: I haven't read the documentation and tried what you demonstrated, but the font size of TOC is still the same. Basically my problem is that I have used \Large or \huge in some places in sections, which is then reflected to TOC. I want to make TOC text independent of font size I have used inside the report.

Comment: @AyushAgnihotri: You'll have to provide the community with a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/5764) that highlights your setup. It should start with `\documentclass` and end with `\end{document}`, contain only the necessary information relating to your problem and replicate it. We want to copy-and-paste-and-compile your code and see exactly what you're seeing. Please also include a picture of the current (and expected, if possible) output.

Comment: I had updated the question and specified what is my issue by modifying your dummy code and I had also added images relating to the problem.

Comment: @AyushAgnihotri: You're using the wrong approach to include font changes within the sectional unit title. That necessarily pushes the changes also to the ToC. I've provided an update to my answer suggestion how you should handle this (with packages).